# SEQUELIZE: Cant access database of an intermediate table

Tags: node.js, database, sequelize.js

I am learning how to use sequelize in nodeJS, I really like it but there are some tables that i am not being be able to access, let me show you:

GIVEN THESE ASSOCIATIONS:

```
Product.belongsTo(User,{constraints:true, onDelete:'CASCADE'});
User.hasMany(Product);

User.hasOne(Cart);
Cart.belongsTo(User);

Cart.belongsToMany(Product,{ through:CartItem});
Product.belongsToMany(Cart,{ through:CartItem});
```

I am trying to build a controller that post products in the cart, it looks like this:

```
exports.addToCart = (req, res, next) => {
    const ID = req.params.cartProductID;
    let newQuantity = 1;
    let fetchedCart;
    req.user
        .getCart().then(cart => {
            fetchedCart = cart;
            return cart.getProducts({ where: { id: ID } });

        }).then(products => {
            let product;
            if (products.length > 0) {
                product = products[0];
            }
            if (product) {
                const oldQuantity = product.cartItems.quantity;
                newQuantity = oldQuantity + 1;
             ...
```

On this last line, I get an error :
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'quantity' of undefined**  if I log that last **product** on the console I can actually see this:
id: 1,

```
  name: 'fdff',
  description: 'fff',
  price: 33,
  createdAt: 2020-03-24T17:19:58.000Z,
  updatedAt: 2020-03-24T17:19:58.000Z,
  userId: 1,
  'cart-item': [cart-item]
```

the question is, what is the correct way to access that 'cart-item' object?

Thanks in advance.
Marc

Comment: cart-item is an array that's why you can't access the quantity prop that belongs to one CartItem object.

Comment: how would you have access it if you were in my shoes?

Comment: If you guarantee that a certain product appears exactly one time in a certain cart then you can try const oldQuantity = product.cartItems[0].quantity; Otherwise you should sum quantity prop of all cartItems using reduce function of an array